# ghci randomio type inference

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am following https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State, and `randomIO` prints an integer in `ghci` directly. Given its type is polymorphic, how does `ghci` know it's `Int` here? Are there some special rules for type inference in `ghci`?

```
GHCi> :m System.Random
GHCi> :t randomIO
randomIO :: Random a => IO a
GHCi> randomIO
-1557093684
GHCi> randomIO
1342278538
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is just simple [Monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction). Polymorphic types such as `Num a => a` are handled like `Integer` if actual type is not specified. Probably this rule also works in `ghci` and you see integer type instead of some unknown type variable.

**UPD 1:** actually the real answer contained under this part of user guide about [defaulting rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci).

**UPD 2:** Case with `Random` type class turned to be more difficult than I expected. So in this case defaulting rules are resolved due to `default (Integer, Double)` declaration which is said in report. Consider next ghci session

```
Prelude System.Random> default ()
Prelude System.Random> randomIO

<interactive>:6:1:
    No instance for (Show (IO a0)) arising from a use of ‘print’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
Prelude System.Random> default (Integer)
Prelude System.Random> randomIO
-7948113563809442883
Prelude System.Random> default (Double)
Prelude System.Random> randomIO
0.41581766590151104
```

Comment: Technically unless there is a function declaration it isn't the monomorphism restriction but just the underlying defaulting rules. Monomorphism restriction is about how defaulting rules apply to function definitions.

Comment: I had a quick looked at the link; "The restriction is turned on by default in compiled modules, and turned off by default at the GHCi prompt (since GHC 7.8.1)." It seems that it's off in ghci. (I was using ghci 7.10.3.)

Comment: @AlbertNetymk yes, as comment above says restriction and defaulting rules are different things. So restriction is turned off but defaulting rules are still applied. See this link: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci

Comment: @Shersh Thanks for the link to ghci user guide; it's very insightful. However, even after relaxing rule 3, it still doesn't match, does it? `Random` is not numeric, and it doesn't belong to [Show, Eq, ...].

Comment: @AlbertNetymk Yes, you're right. `Random` is not a numeric type. But user guide says that «At the GHCi prompt ... Rule 2 above is relaxed thus» in next way: `All of the classes Ci are single-parameter type classes`. So  because `Random` is exactly a single-parameter type class defaulting rules applies.

Comment: @Shersh I thought rule 1,2,3 need to be satisfied at the same time. Looking at 2010 report 4.3.4 https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-750004.3, it uses "and" explicitly.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk It has to do with `default declaration` which is `default (Integer, Double)`. I've updated my answer again.

Comment: @Shersh Thanks for the detailed illustration. The reasoning is easy to follow once we decide that `a` is defaultable. However, in this case, it's *not*, because it doesn't match all three rules, right? Specifically, "Rule 3 above is relaxed this: At least one of the classes Ci is numeric, or is Show, Eq, Ord, Foldable or Traversable."