# Why does ghci outputs (Num a) => a for :t 4 and not (Ord a) => a?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, typeclass

When I enter `:t 4` in ghci I get

```
Prelude> :t 4
4 :: Num t => t
```

I understand why `4` is not only an Int or an Integer and that it is infered bottom up but I do not understand why `4` is not shown as an `Ord t => t` or even more correct something like this:

```
4 :: (Ord t || Num t) => t
```

Because `4` is both an `Ord` and a `Num` but `Ord` and `Num` have no connection...

So why does `:t 4` output only `Num`?

Comment: This is described in the [haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1360006.4.1)

Comment: Suppose I gave `4` the type `Ord t => t`. Now I note that `Bool` is an instance of `Ord`. Therefore `4 :: Bool`. Should `4 :: Bool` be `True` or `False`, and why?

Comment: @Lee Btw, there is similar question regarding type defaulting rules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251728/ghci-randomio-type-inference  I tried to answer it and understand report but still has no clear view. Maybe more experienced _Haskell_ users can help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not all types with instances for `Num` also have instances for `Ord`, and you only need the `fromInteger` part of `Num` to have the overloaded numeric literals Haskell has. For example, `Complex` from [`Data.Complex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Complex.html) has a `Num` instance but no `Ord`. In this case, `4` is *not* an `Ord`.

```
ghci> import Data.Complex
ghci> let x = 1 :: Complex Double
ghci> let y = 2 :: Complex Double
ghci> x < y
<interactive>
    * No instance for (Ord (complex Double)) arising from use of `<'
    * In the expression: x < y
      In the equation for `it': it = x < y
ghci>
```

As @Lee commented, this is the behavior outlined in the [report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1360006.4.1).

Comment: Note that you explained why the type isn't `(Ord t, Num t) => t`, not why it isn't `(Ord t || Num t) => t` (which isn't valid syntax, but, I assume, is meant to say "t might be an `Ord` *or* a `Num`).

Comment: @sepp2k That is true - I hadn't interpreted the `||` that way. That said, I think I indirectly answer this...

Comment: Ok thx. The thing with the` fromIntegral` in the Link provided by @Lee was very helpful. Even more helpful was the link to Section [3.4.3](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4). So when I write `(3<4)`: to infer the actual type of `4` the compiler has to find a Type that satisfies `(Num t, Ord t) => t`, which could be one of `Int`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Double` (or even more with external Modules). That's ambiguous and would produce an Error. But for Num these ambiguities are resolved by defaulting to (in this case) Integer.